# Problems with width properties in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am having an issue with a landscape orientation game that I working on in Swift. It was adapted from a portrait mode tutorial and code, however I have set the correct orientation in the project settings, as well as setting the dimensions in the GamePlayScene.sks file (and saving before building)

If I add a sprite in the main didMoveToView function, such as the background, then the width property works as expected:

```
    let background : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"background")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX, y: self.frame.minY)
    background.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    background.size.width = self.frame.size.width
```

however, when I try to add in the physics object for the ground, called from my GroundNode.swift class, I can only get the ground to stretch for half of the screen by using similar settings. It is as if the node thinks that the screen is in portrait all of a sudden.

I am placing this code immediately after the above code in the main function:

```
    var ground = GroundNode(size: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 100))
    ground.zPosition = 20
    self.addChild(ground)
```

and this is an abbreviated version of my ground node class:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class GroundNode: SKSpriteNode {
    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: size)
        self.name = "Ground"
        setUpPhysicsBody()
}

func setUpPhysicsBody(){
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
    self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

This is the result when I run my project:

[image]

As you can see, the background is fitted all the way across as expected, yet the ground node only covers half the screen. It is also not interacting correctly with any objects that are meant to be standing on it.. they float quite a bit above, yes when I remove the ground, they fall through correctly, although this is probably because their node classes are also suffering from the same issue.

Ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that 0,0 is actually at the bottom and in the middle of the screenshot as your ground node gets it's position set to 0,0 and that's where it starts.

You are setting the position of the background node but not the ground node, try setting the ground node's position in the same way.

```
ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX, y: self.frame.minY)
```

Comment: The ground node is actually the black rectangle on the left.. It would normally be set to clearColor() . The actual ground, i.e. the grassy bit, is part of the BG image for now. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stee who got me thinking about the location of 0,0 on the node, I realised I had not set the anchor point, and that it was defaulting to the centre of my ground node.

By adding the following:

```
self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

my code worked as expected.